Data validation apply range
I am trying to apply validation to a range (A1:A5000), but when I delete a row from this range (let’s say A3000), the range of application changes to (A1: A3000). Does anyone know how to fix this?
I tried creating a named range, but Google Sheets does not allow me to use a range like that or select the entire column A:A.
The validation type is a dropdown list from the list I have in sheet2!A1:D1. For example in cell A30, the validation is a dropdown list of sheet2!A30:D30.

This doesn't look like a question for StackOverflow. Perhaps try a different StackExchange site.

For example in cell A30, the validation is a dropdown list of sheet2!A30:D30.Would you clarify something: do you mean that every row of data has a unique validation rule that aligns with the equivalent row in Sheet2?

Would you please edit the question to include an example of a validation rule.
